# Combing for loops

Tags: python

When flattening for loops, you would do something like this:

```
for a, b, c in itertools.product(x1, x2, x3):
    ...
```

But how would you handle the case where one of the elements is to be used as a parameter to retrieve a list also to be traversed? For example:

```
for a, b in itertools.product(x1, get_b_elements(a)):
    ...
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: So, you don't know which lists you're getting the product of until you've gotten their product? Either you have an impossible task or you need to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can only flatten so far. Here you have reached the point at which you must stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for a in x1:
    for b in get_b_elements(a):
       #do something with (a, b)
```

Just to list an alternative:

```
for (a, b) in [(a_i, b_i) for a_i in x1 for b_i in get_b_elements(a_i)]:
    #do something with (a, b)
```

As @wim notes, none of these "flatten" the loop as you want.

Comment: That's fine and readable, but it doesn't flatten the loop, which I think is what the question was asking about

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
alphabets = [a,b,c,d]
xs = [x1,x2,x3]

itertools.product(alphabets, xs)
```